# Unit Test in angular js controller that call service with http request

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to do a unit test for an angularjs controller. The controller makes a call to a service that implements an http get. After making that call in case of success a value is assigned to a scope variable. But the case is that I do not find how to simulate that action. Here I leave my code.

Service:

```
export class AnalysisService extends Observable {

constructor($log, $http, tenant, trainer){
    "ngInject";

    // call super constructor
    super();

    this.$http = $http;
    this.tenant = tenant;
    this.trainer = trainer;
}

getDeploys(project, analysis)
{
    return this.$http.get(`${this.trainer}/${this.tenant.id}/projects/${project}/analyses/${analysis}/deploys`);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
export class ModelsController {

constructor($scope, $routeParams, analysis){
  $scope.opt = false;
  $scope.data = {};

  analysis.getDeploys($scope.project, $scope.analysisId)
        .then(
            function(analDep)
            {
                $scope.opt = true;
                $scope.data = analDep.data; 
            }, 
            function(analDepErr)
            {
                console.log(analDepErr);
            },
        );

}
```

Unit Test:

```
import 'angular-mocks';

describe('ModelsController', function() {
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("my-trainer"))
    var $controller, mockAnalysis;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, analysis){
      $controller = _$controller_;
      mockAnalysis = analysis;
    }));

    describe('Unit test Controller ModelsController', function() {
      var $scope, controller;

      beforeEach(function() {
       var fakeHttpPromise = {
       then: () => {
         return {
           data: {
             _embedded: {
                collectors: [
                 {id:1, name:'demo1'},
                 {id:2, name:'demo2'},
                 {id:3, name:'demo2'}
             ]}
           }};
        }};
      });

     spyOn(mockAnalysis, 'getDeploys').and.returnValue(fakeHttpPromise);

    controller = $controller('ModelsController', { $scope: $scope, analysis: mockAnalysis });

    it('checking $scope.opt and $scope.data after call analysis', function() {
        //..........................

        // here my problem. I have done many things but none works for me
        //.........................  
    });
})
```

Comment: **retrieveByProject** where this method in your service??

Comment: My error when copy an paste code. The method is getDeploys

Answer (score 0):

The way you are implementing **fakeHttpPromise**, wont work. As your then method wont be called automatically. Use $q service and return promise and resolve with your data which eventually calls **your** then method.

Inject $q service, you have not injected $scope as well. provide injected scope in your controller

```
beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, analysis, $q, $scope){
      $controller = _$controller_;
      mockAnalysis = analysis;
      $q = $q;
      $scope = $scope;
    }));
```

Now return promise :

```
describe('Unit test Controller ModelsController', function() {
      var $scope, controller;
      var data = { // data to be returned
             _embedded: {
                collectors: [
                 {id:1, name:'demo1'},
                 {id:2, name:'demo2'},
                 {id:3, name:'demo2'}
             ]}
           };

      beforeEach(function() {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         var promise = deferred.promise; // return promise
         deferred.resolve(data) // above defined data

      });

     spyOn(mockAnalysis, 'getDeploys').and.returnValue(promise ); // return promise
     controller = $controller('ModelsController', { $scope: $scope, analysis: mockAnalysis });
     $scope.apply() // this will make your .then() method called.
```